# Form Plugin, Call to undefined method EE_Functions::form_declarations()

Tags: forms, plugin

I am writing a form from within a plugin module using EEE 2.6.1

```
    class Meal_form {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->EE =& get_instance();
    }

    public function form()
    {

        $form_data = array(
            "id"    => $this->EE->TMPL->form_id,
            "class" => $this->EE->TMPL->form_class
        );

        $tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata;

        $form = $this->EE->functions->form_declarations($form_data) . $tagdata . "</form>";

        return $form;
    }
}
```

I receive the following error on form_declarations();
Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Functions::form_declarations()

Any ideas on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method name is `form_declaration()`, not `form_declarations()`.

Comment: Doh!, there goes my second stupid question of the year....